# В каких случаях использовать void ?

Tags: php

Привет . 
В каких случаях использовать ключевое слово void ? 
Может это слово можно опустить ?

void - значит нет никакого типа . Если используется в функции то функция не возвращает никакого значения

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void

Comment: А в php разве есть слово `void`? Может здесь эта метка лишняя?

Comment: @BOPOH, тут чего-то просматривается http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792827/void-as-return-type

Comment: @Visman, void не был добавлен к типам PHP

Comment: @Etki, значит автора вопроса надо просветить по этому поводу хорошо оформленным ответом.

Comment: @BOPOH в php слово `void` [используется](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.pseudo-types.php) только в документации, как псевдо-тип, чтобы обозначить, что «возвращенное значение бесполезно. void в списке параметров означает, что функция не принимает параметров.»

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В PHP понятие `void` абсолютно условно, в самом языке этого понятия нет - обычно ключевое слово void используется в программировании для обозначения отсутствия возвращаемого значения вообще (других применений, кроме void-указателя, навскидку вспомнить не могу, но это не очень важно в этом контексте). В PHP же подобный подход отсутствует вообще, и любая функция или метод вернут `null` в случае отсуствия возвращаемого значения. Поэтому такой штуки просто нет в языке, но есть в документации, к которой мы вернемся через абзац.

В PHP 7 вводится расширенная поддержка строгой типизации, однако она не полностью покрывает примитивные типы и все равно не имеет типа void. Насколько я могу предполагать, это сделано именно из-за того, что реализация *отсутствия возвращаемого значения в принципе* довольно сложна для впиливания в движок, и, кроме того, обратно несовместима, а разработчики PHP, судя по тому, что я явидел, делают довольно большой упор на нее.

Что до документации (уточню - я имею в виду PHPDoc), то здесь void наконец существует, и вполне применим. Хороший код, с моей точки зрения, в случае невозможности вычислить значение в методе/функции должен либо бросать исключение, если это критическая секция, либо возвращать null. И вот здесь, для того чтобы отделять те методы, которые не возвращают вообще ничего, от тех, в которых возврат null зависит от логики (ну и, кроме того, это отличный способ указать, что метод реально производит побочные эффекты и ничего не возвращает):

```
class InMemoryCache
{
    private $storage = [];
    /**
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    public function fetch($key)
    {
         return isset($storage[$key]) ? $storage[$key] : null;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function flush()
    {
        $this->storage = [];
    }
}
```

В целом же можно только процитировать @Sergiks:

> в php слово void используется только в документации, как псевдо-тип, чтобы обозначить, что «возвращенное значение бесполезно. void в списке параметров означает, что функция не принимает параметров.»

Comment: Благодарен за материал .

Comment: Кто-то [предлагал](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type) ввести в php 7 тип *void*, но предложение было снято.